# Mounting a USB Mass Storage Device in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, mount, usb

How do I mount a USB Mass Storage Device in Debian?

The USB Stick is working on other computers.

I have used `dmesg` which returned useful information about the USB Stick. It is attached to `/dev/sdc`.

I tried to mount it using `mount -t` with different filesystem type parameters (ntfs, vfat, fat16, usbfs and usbdevfs).

Only one of these parameters seemed to actually result in something. It was `usbfs`. However, `ls` did not show the files which I stored on the USB Stick. Instead, it showed:

```
001  devices
```

I presume `usbfs` is not the right filesystem type. If it is not, then what is?

I am unable to use the Internet on the server for downloading specific packages for instance, since I am trying to install my network card driver on my server via USB.

Comment: "Without using the Internet"? What on earth does that mean?

Comment: This would be on-topic for SuperUser or Unix & Linux, but it doesn't fit here and since I can't discern whether those fires are wrong or really what you're asking about in regards to, "Without using the Internet" (which you're on), I'm not keen to migrate.

Comment: I try my best to explain my question, but all i get is negative feedback. It means that I cannot install any packages or anything.

Comment: I need to install my network card driver for my server via a USB stick.

Comment: @JeffFerland Why can't I just ask this question about my server here? I find it not very friendly of people to dump my question like that. I spend a lot of time researching and trying to explain it the best I can.

Comment: @user907560 At the outset, your question is indistinguishable from end-user support and doesn't provide the information we need to know that the flash drive works elsewhere. This further information helps a lot. +1.

Comment: @user907560 Server Fault is a site for professional system administrators, with a very specific scope described in our site [FAQ]. As it stands there is nothing about your question that indicates it is in the realm of "professional system administration" (as opposed to "end user asking a question about their personal/desktop machine") - This is why you are getting "negative feedback". Your question is not "bad", it just does not appear to be on-topic per the site's scope/FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When mounting with `-t usbfs`, the source doesn't matter. `usbfs` is a [DevFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) virtual filesystem. Its contents are points to various devices.

Even USB drives are usually partitioned like hard drives, so you'll want to check `ls /dev/sdc*`. You'll probably see a `/dev/sdc1`. As many others have said, you'll find that `mount` usually detects the right filesystem. Mounting `/dev/sdc` directly is failing because you're trying to mount the partition table as a filesystem. Mounting with `-t usbfs` worked because virtual filesystem mounts ignore the source argument.

Comment: I would like to vote up, but I need to wait for some reputation. Thank you very much! Very thourough information.

Comment: My server is up again! :)

Answer (score 2):

`mount` should detect the filesystem automatically in most cases. Your USB drive may be partitioned which is why `sdc` won't mount. Try the following:

```
mkdir /mnt/usb
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/usb
```

If this doesn't work, the output of `blkid` may help you identify the correct device name.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to vote up, but I need to wait for some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/sdc is the full usb device, you cant mount it. You need to mount something like /dev/sdc1 (first partition) /sev/sdc2 (second partition), etc. The filesystem is autodetected, but  you need to add the mount point, for example:

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

Will mount the first partition  in /mnt directory.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to vote up, but I need to wait for some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question

Mounting a USB Mass Storage Device in Debian

identify your Stick with fdisk or similar and mount with

```
mount /dev/[device] /mnt
```

This works unless you have a an old debian version or strange filesystem on the stick.

However it seams you are asking the wrong question for your problem. Which is, "how do I install a driver for NetworkCard XY on debian (Version X) from CD or USB" ;-)